# Is ending of .text section of ELF also the ending of instruction execution?

Tags: linux, elf

If I have to design a simulator of sorts, can the ending address of .text section (found out by starting address and size of .text) of an ELF be considered the ending place for the instructions?

In the sense, can the last address of .text section be treated as the last instruction address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can the last address of .text section be treated as the last instruction address?

The last address of `.text` section is indeed (the end of) the last instruction in  *that* section.

But nothing in ELF specification prevents the file from having executable instructions in *other* sections. Indeed, this is very common. For example:

```
 readelf -WS /bin/ls | grep ' AX'
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000004000 004000 000017 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000004020 004020 0006b0 10  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS        00000000000046d0 0046d0 000018 08  AX  0   0  8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        00000000000046f0 0046f0 01254e 00  AX  0   0 16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS        0000000000016c40 016c40 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
```

All of `.init`, `.fini`, `.text` etc. contain executable instructions.

**Update:**

> So if I can run the following command on the elf input file, can I consider the last address in the last executable section as end of instructions?

If you are writing an emulator, surely you wouldn't want to run `readelf` and parse its output, but instead would parse the info *directly* by reading the `ELF` file and parsing its contents.

Also note that an executable can `mmap(..., PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, ...)` or `mprotect` additional executable sections, so knowing the last address of instruction in the `ELF` file is somewhat pointless.

Comment: So if I can run the following command on the elf input file, can I consider the last address in the last executable section as end of instructions? Or is my understanding of ELF completely wrong?